# How to cast parent into child in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, parent

**I am doing this:**

```
Child child = (Child)parent;
```

Which gives me an error, I found it isn't possible to do it like this. I don't know exactly why, but I think it should be possible, if `Child` class inherits from `Parent` class, it contains the `Parent` object data.

**My questions are:**

- Why it doesnt work?

- How can i make this work, without setting every single parent's
  attribute like this

:

```
class Parent{
    public int parameter1;//...
    public int parameter1000;
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public Child(Parent parent)
{
        this.parameter1 = parent.parameter1;//...
        this.parameter1000 = parent.parameter1000;
}
}
```

Comment: It **is** possible to do it like that, **iff** `parent` actually refers to a `Child` instance.

Comment: What type is `parent`?

Comment: Well i have some data loaded from file, something like: 
public Parent loadMe()
{
Parent p = new Parent();
...
return p;
}
and then i need to recast this parent to some of its children

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible. A dog is an animal, but an animal is not (always) a dog. Casting does not magically convert one type of object into another. It just tells the compiler that you know better than the compiler what the actual type of the object is. If you need a `Child`, then you need to do `new Child()` instead of `new Parent()`.

Comment: I have multiple children, I cant just make 20 methods with the same content, only returning the one child, it is possible, but I believe it could be done much more easier and better.

Comment: If you shared some more code, it might become clearer what you're actually trying to do. If your data-loading code is only creating instances of `Parent`, it's not possible to cast these objects to `Child`. Do you even need inheritance here? Could you just have a field called "type" on the parent class to determine what kind of object (child) is in question?

Comment: I have data structures very similar to each other, the same attributes i have in parent class and differents in children classes, that is why i am using inheritance, because of the same attributes (like 90% is same).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well you could just do :

```
Parent p = new Child();
// do whatever
Child c = (Child)p;
```

Or if you have to start with a pure Parent object you could consider having a constructor in your parent  class and calling :

```
class Child{
    public Child(Parent p){
        super(p);
    }
}
class Parent{
    public Parent(Args...){
        //set params
    }
}
```

Or the composition model :

```
class Child {
    Parent p;
    int param1;
    int param2;
}
```

You can directly set the parent in that case.

You can also use Apache Commons BeanUtils to do this. Using its BeanUtils class you have access to a lot of utility methods for populating JavaBeans properties via reflection.

To copy all the common/inherited properties from a parent object to a child class object you can use its static copyProperties() method as:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(parentObj,childObject);
```

Note however that this is a heavy operation.

Comment: Hmm, this is possible, but still need to set parameters line by line.

Comment: what is the int fields for ? @likaa

Comment: I dont really have int fields in the parent class, i have different attributes, and some of them are different types, if i have only int params, i would put it into array.

Comment: well you could also move from inheritence to composition model.

Comment: @AkashRoyChoudhury That is very good idea, if I wont find better solution i'll use it!

Comment: @likaa ok so you just want an easy way to set the properties. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

change 'this' to 'super' in your child constructor, and remove the parent parameter, instead replace that with the two parameters 
int parameter1;//...int parameter1000; :)

```
class Parent{
public int parameter1;//...
public int parameter1000;
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public Child(int parameter1, int parameter1000)
    {
        super.parameter1 = parameter1
        super.parameter1000 = parameter1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess i dont understand your answer, i wanted to show that i have multiple parameters in parent class (that is why parameter1 ... parameter1000) and my question was, how to do it without 1000 lines of setting this parameters.

Comment: what if parent class fields are private ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to cast you parent into the child class? If the given Object (given as a Parent object) was created as a child class, you can access the correct functions without the cast. Here is an example:
In the main you see a Vector 'ps' to store Parent objects, but added are Child objects which extend from the Parent. While iterateing through that vector, I dont know which kind of child I get next (thus I cannot cast to the correct class), but due to the keyword **Override** of the function I call, the correct child/method is used.

```
import java.util.Vector;
import lib.Parent;
import lib.C1;
import lib.C2;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        C2 c2 = new C2();
        
        ps.add(c1);
        ps.add(c2);
        
        for(int k = 0; k < ps.size(); k++){
            ps.get(k).setInteger(); // no cast needed
            System.out.println("stored entity " + ps.get(k).i);
        }
        // or use a ranged for loop
        for(Parent p: ps){
            p.setInteger();
            System.out.println("stored entity " + p.i);
        }
    }
     
    static Vector<Parent> ps = new Vector<>();
}
```

The Parent class: The keyword **abstract** forces every child to implement that method, so if you have a Parent object you can safely call this method. Since the Parent class itself is abstract you wont have an object which is just a Parent object since that is not allowed and wont compile.

```
package lib;
public abstract class Parent{
    public Integer i;
    
    public abstract void setInteger();
}
```

And here are two Child classes which have an different implementation of the **setInteger()**  method.

```
package lib;
import lib.Parent;

public class C1 extends Parent{
    
    @Override
    public void setInteger(){
        i = new Integer(1);
    }
}
```

Second Child:

```
package lib;
import lib.Parent;

public class C2 extends Parent{
     
    @Override
    public void setInteger(){
        i = new Integer(2);
    }
}
```

The Output is

```
stored entity 1
stored entity 2
stored entity 1  <-- ranged for
stored entity 2  <-- ranged for
```

Edit:
The file structre looks like this

```
|-MyClass.java
|-lib
  |-Parent.java
  |-C1.java
  |-C2.java
```